# Allow users to manualy overide geolocation

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, geolocation, geo

I have been looking for a way to allow users to manually override geolocation on a website (Incase its incorrect).

Thank you anyone who takes time out to respond to my post have googled allot but with no progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a textbox for the user to enter their location. Then submit that to a geocoding API service such as Google Maps, geocoding.us, Yahoo Maps, etc. returns and use that result in your application.

If you use the Google Maps API, it is very simple to geocode an address. `address` is a textfield that the user inputs a street address. `latlng` is a text field that holds the outputted lat/long.

```
$('#searchButton').click(function() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( {'address': $('#address').val() }, function(data, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      $('#latlng').val(data[0].geometry.location.lat+", "+data[0].geometry.location.lng);
    else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

See https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Comment: Thanks for your answer is there anyway you can show an example code on how to do this would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Hey thanks for your examples and taking time to reply I have to wait 4 minutes to click the tick next to the answer! Been looking all day for an example like this!